# Android sqlite return args if not exist

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm new in Android-Sqlite and I have this issue,

I have a table with the following values,

```
id, name
1, test1
2, test2
3, test3
```

I query this table with a set of args and I use IN clause like below,

```
select name from TABLE where id in (1,2,44)
```

As you can see 44 isn't there, is it possible to get the name for the IDs that are there and the IDs of the ones that are not like below?

```
result = (test1, test2, 44)
```

Comment: Extreamly vague. How to get id of something that isn't there? Or are you referring to returning 44 as a non existing id?

Comment: You can write separate queries for sure and if query if cursor.moveToFirst() is null then the query had no results and you can return the id, otherwise return the name you got from your query

Comment: Yes, 44 isn't there in the DB

Comment: You could use a temporary table with just an id column that contains the ids your looking for .  then do a left join from temporary table to the existing table then present the results with a select ifnull(existingtable.id,temporarytable.id) from temporarytable join existingtable on temporarytable.id = existingtable.id

Comment: You can make a second query to find the NON matching items. `select name from TABLE where id not in (1,2,44)`